# Date formatting not working with cellFilter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

In response i will receive a date like '2016-09-07 20:00:23.234 IST' and am trying format the date like '07/Sep/2016 20:00:23.234' with help of ui-grid cellFilter.

like

```
     {
       "name": "creationTimestamp", 
       "type": "date", 
       "cellFilter": "date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss.SSS'" 
     }
```

But it's not working it. still i am getting as result like'2016-09-07 20:00:23.234 IST'. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

we can also use custom filter, if we want to do handle timezone
 {
       "name": "creationTimestamp", 
       "type": "date", 
       "cellFilter": "dateConversion" 
     }

app.filter('dateConversion', function(){
  return function(date,timezone){
    return (timezone ? moment.tz(date) :moment.utc(date)).format('DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.sss');
  };
})

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with cellFilter:

```
'date:"dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.sss"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps now but i have the same issue where my date was string formatted using moment. I ended up using toDatefrom moment

my creationTimestamp was:

```
moment.utc(utcDate).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:ss A')
```

this was failing during sort, So i changed it to

```
moment(moment.utc(utcDate).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:ss A')).toDate()
```

and changed my cell filter as, removed the type 'date'

```
{
   "name": "creationTimestamp", 
   "cellFilter": "date:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'" 
 }
```

Now the display and sorting works fine on ui-grid